# Unit of work, Repository, Entity framework / Max pool size was reached / Parallel foreach

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, repository, unit-of-work

I have 6000 items and every item process on msSql with parallel foreach. 
When i start app throw max pool size was reached exception after a while. 
I tried `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set 50 and i don't get an error but app working to much slow.

What can i do for this error.

my codes are like this;

```
using RPandUOW.EntityModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace RPandUOW.Repositories
{
    public interface IGenericRepository<T>
        where T:class
    {
        T FindById(object EntityId);
        IEnumerable<T> Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>> Filter = null);
        void Insert(T Entity);
        void Update(T Entity);
        void Delete(object EntityId);
        void Delete(T Entity);
    }

    public class ShopRepository<T>
        :IGenericRepository<T>
        where T:class
    {
        private ShopContext _context;
        private DbSet<T> _dbSet;
        public ShopRepository(ShopContext Context)
        {
            _context = Context;
           _dbSet = _context.Set<T>();
        }
        public virtual T FindById(object EntityId)
        {
            return _dbSet.Find(EntityId);
        }
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>> Filter = null)
        {
            if (Filter != null)
            {
                return _dbSet.Where(Filter);
            }
            return _dbSet;
        }
        public virtual void Insert(T entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Add(entity);
        }
        public virtual void Update(T entityToUpdate)
        {
            _dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            _context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        public virtual void Delete(object EntityId)
        {
            T entityToDelete = _dbSet.Find(EntityId);
           Delete(entityToDelete);
        }
        public virtual void Delete(T Entity)
        {
            if (_context.Entry(Entity).State == EntityState.Detached) //Concurrency için
            {
                _dbSet.Attach(Entity);
            }
            _dbSet.Remove(Entity);
        }
    }}
```

---

```
using RPandUOW.EntityModel;
using RPandUOW.Repositories;
using System;
using System.Transactions;

namespace RPandUOW.UnitOfWorks
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork
        :IDisposable
    {  
        void Save();
        // Başka operasyonlar da tanımlanabilir.
        // void OpenTransaction();
        // void CloseTransaction();
        // gibi
    }

    public class ShopUnitOfWork
        :IUnitOfWork
    {
        private ShopContext _context = new ShopContext();
        private ShopRepository<Category> _categoryRepository;
        private ShopRepository<Product> _productRepository;
        private bool _disposed = false;
        public ShopRepository<Category> CategoryRepository
        {
            get
            {
                if (_categoryRepository == null)
                   _categoryRepository = new ShopRepository<Category>(_context);
                return _categoryRepository;
            }
        }
        public ShopRepository<Product> ProductRepository
        {
            get
            {
                if (_productRepository == null)
                    _productRepository = new ShopRepository<Product>(_context);
                return _productRepository;
            }
        }
        public void Save()
        {
            using (TransactionScope tScope = new TransactionScope())
           {
                _context.SaveChanges();
                tScope.Complete();
            }
        }
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this._disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this._disposed = true;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have two methods like this for raw sql execut : `Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(sqlQuery)`

```
Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
{
 result = bl.run(item);
});
```

Comment: Yeap, It is working `MaxDegreeOfParallelism=50`

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the pool size and increase the number of parallel threads.

I also suspect that you may have an instance/close issue with your UoW/Repo pattern.  How are you instancing your classes?  More code would help.

Comment: You have each save method as a transaction yet it's already a transaction - remove that transaction code.  Also as mentioned above, Parallel tasks are not necessarily good for queries.  What happens inside your Run() method?  select, then insert/update?  You doing a lot of these in parallel and all of them in a wrapped transaction may be causing table locks.

Comment: Lastly, it sounds like you need to figure out where the performance issue actually is (called a hot spot) then refactor the code upwards to make it efficient

Comment: Transaction not important for me, i just working with select queries. Run() method insides sometimes 5, sometimes 10 select query working sametime. Actualy that's not my problem i think. Parallelism open more connection. but my code not working like singleton pattern. (and i try this, so slow)

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong inside of your Run() method

Comment: It's working on iisExpress(debug mode) without errors and `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`